# java make a method wait for a response of another process

Tags: java, process, response, wait

In my program, I connect to an interpreter process for another language. I need the program sometimes to ask the interpreter several things and use it's response.

The process is stored in a IProcess variable and the communication is done via the IStreamsProxy of the process. to recieve the response, I added an IStreamListener to the IStreamsProxy.

However, when I write to the IStreamsProxy (with the write() method), I need the code to wait for the response, e.g. the streamAppend-method of the listener to be called.

I tried to use the wait() and notify() method, but I don't know on what objects I should call them.

The query class which makes the communication calls a method like this:

```
/**
 * Sends a command to the interpreter. Makes the current thread wait for an answer of the interpreter.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private synchronized void send(String command) throws IOException{
    this.s48Proxy.write(command);
    try {
        System.out.println("waiting for reply");
        this.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("interruption exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and the listener:

```
private class Listener implements IStreamListener {

    private Query query;

    public Listener(Query query) {
        super();
        this.query = query;
    }

    @Override
    public void streamAppended(String arg0, IStreamMonitor arg1) {
        System.out.println("got interpreter answer");
        query.setCurrentOutput(arg0.substring(0, arg0.lastIndexOf("\n")).trim());
        query.notify();
    }
}
```

The `streamAppend()` method calls the `notify()`-method on the query class. However, this does not work. *"Waiting for reply"* is the last response I get.

How can I do this? Or are there any other methods I could use to achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Object#wait` & `Object#notifiy`.

```
// @ IStreamsProxy
synchronized( someMonitor ) {
  someMonitor.wait( /* time? */ );
}

// @ Listener
synchronized( someMonitor ) {
  someMonitor.notify();
}
```

-> [Javadoc Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--)

Comment: yeah i tried this, but i could not achieve any results. i edit my question to what i exactly did.

Comment: You have to make sure; notify is not already called when you call wait(). Have you tryed to debug if notify() is really called?

Comment: no it isn't, i edited my code above, the streamAppend method seems not to be called at all.

Comment: okay i had a bug in my code for the interpreter, the notify method is now called. but the thing is, i get an java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException now when calling notify.

Comment: You have to use the code provided in my answer. You have forgotten to synchronize over query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a semaphore like boolean waitingForResponse. Set this to true when you make your call, then go into

while(waitingForResponse){
    sleep(99) //should be your average response time from your call
}

In your listener, set waitinForResponse to false.

Comment: that works, but this is a busy-waiting. is there a better solution?