# Call to Asynchronous Function

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, dao, parse-platform

I am using parse.com as my backend service for my Android application. I wish to make separation between my activities and parse, for this purpose I have created service class witch will bridge activities and parse (backend). Most parse functions are asynchronous and I don't really know how to handle them. For example if I want to login with a user I will call the service object that should execute login with parse login function. So here is my code in the activity:

```
LoginService login = new LoginService("username", "password");
login.login();
//from here it is not correct
if(login.getLoginStatus() == 2) {
   //user loggedin 
}...
```

and my service code is:

```
public LoginSrvice(String userName, String pass) 
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public void loginUser() 
    {
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(userName, pass, new LogInCallback() 
        {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                 if (user != null) {
                      logedIn = 1;
                 } else {
                      logedIn = 2;
                 }
            }
        });
    }

    public int getLoginStatus() 
    {
        return logedIn;
    }
```

My question is how should I do it right? how can i keep both activities and services separated but still wait for the response in the activity till the service class will get the callback from parse. 
Thanks for the HELP in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not an Android developer, but in Java you can use the wait() notifiy() methods of objects for wait until something happens. 
But take into consideration you can enter into in a race condition where you wait() after the notify() has been already called.

Comment: can you give me some example please?

Comment: In this entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713786/java-make-a-method-wait-for-a-response-of-another-process/7713815#7713815 you will find a sample. As I said, is a generic procedure in Java

Answer (score 1):

If a Service's lifecycle isn't tied to your Activity you can [bind to it](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and then [get a reference to the Service via the Binder object](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#tutorial_ownservice). The simplest communication method is to use a Messenger object in a way similar to [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/Downloader/src/com/commonsware/android/downloader).

In this particular instance, I assume you're waiting for the login before the user can use anything other than the login screen. You could probably perform the login in an AsyncTask or, even better, a Fragment/Loader model. In the appropriate callback method, you'd perform the post-login action.

Comment: my service class is not an Android service class, it is just some buffer between the activity and the parse methods. I couldn't find any solution on the net. AsyncTask is good only for one task I may need later to call more then one task from my service, say all CRUD oppression. If there is any solution I would be thankful!

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar question but for Parse and iOS. I posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226727/how-to-cleanly-encapsulate-and-execute-in-sequence-a-series-of-background-tasks) on SO along with the answer I found. You will probably find yourself writing Cloud Code in JavaScript for Parse. For that you will need to learn to use Promises. My solution to managing the asynchrony in iOS was to implement Promises in iOS. They allowed me to encapsulate my background Parse operations in a very clean way. The same trick may work for you.

It possible that the code I posted to GitHub will be of help, but it's in Objective-C.

-Bob

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear why you need an abstraction around Parse's API, but I would recommend something very simple. Parse's API already handles thread safety, so you can write your interface to query Parse state and KISS. I.e.

```
class UserAbstraction {
  // You may find it useful to also use the callback object for other reasons.
  public static void logIn(string userName, string password) {
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(userName, password);
  }

  public static boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need it to separate the activities from the backend calls, maybe tomorrow I'll change my backend provider.